# Getting Error: EIO: i/o error, read in Expo for React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am not able to connect my physical device through expo IOS app after "yarn start" and expo launch metro bundler, after a few seconds this error message pops up.

Please how do i resolve this?

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: EIO: i/o error, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:506:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:331:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users.....node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:220:39)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\.....\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:78:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\emeka\workspace\fullstack\Reactnative\Confusion\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:98:9)
    at C:\Users\.....\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:103:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\....\Confusion\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:95:12) {
  type: 'Error',
  errno: -4070,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EIO'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling expo solved it. I figured maybe some files got deleted while install npm packages.